# Clases herencia super Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, herencia

En cuanto a la herencia de una clase hijo con una padre. Se que en la clase hijo, poniendo super(atributo heredado) en el constructor, estas heredando los atributos de la clase padre.

En cuanto a los metodos si hay un metodo con mismo nombre en clase padre y otro en clase hijo? Se puede poner super en el metodo de clase hijo?, para cuando llamo al metodo hijo (mediante un objeto de clase hijo) tambien se ejecute el metodo con mismo nombre de clase padre?. En Python lo permite, pero aun no pude encontrar eso en javascript

```
class padre{
  constructor(nombre,apellido){
    this.nombre=nombre
    this.apellido=apellido
  }
 imprimi(){
   console.log("hola si si "+this.nombre)
 }
}

class hijo extends  padre{
constructor(nombre,apellido,edad){
   super(nombre,apellido)//con este super heredo nombre y apellido.
    this.edad=edad
 
}
  imprimi(){
//aca se puede poner un super? asi cuando llamo este  metodo con el objeto de clase hijo, tambien se ejecuta el metodo de mismo nombre de clase padre?*  
    console.log("hola "+this.nombre+ this.edad)
  }
}

let hijo1=new hijo("hector","luis",15)
hijo1.imprimi()
```

Comment: "con este super heredo nombre y apellido" <- no, con este super haces una llamada al constructor en el padre... nombre y apellido, si estan definidos como variables de clase, los heredaste (y por eso la herencia)

Answer (score 2):

Sí es posible, en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) se explica que puedes acceder al constructor de la clase padre con:

```
super(parametros)
```

Y también puedes acceder a sus métodos:

```
super.nombreDeMetodo()
```

```js
class padre {
  constructor(nombre,apellido) {
    this.nombre=nombre
    this.apellido=apellido
  }
 imprimi(){
   console.log("hola si si "+this.nombre)
 }
}

class hijo extends  padre{
  constructor(nombre,apellido,edad){
    super(nombre,apellido)//con este super heredo nombre y apellido.
    this.edad=edad
 
  }
  imprimi(){
    // Acceder al método de la clase padre
    super.imprimi();
    console.log("hola "+this.nombre+ this.edad)
  }
}

let hijo1=new hijo("hector","luis",15)
hijo1.imprimi()
```